# Spring boot with flyway - use a dynamic db password

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I want to integrate flyway in my spring boot project, however i cannot write the password to the database in the properties file.

with my normal datasource i use the following code

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SwatDataBaseConfig {

    @Value("${swat.decrypt.location}")
    private String fileLocation;

    @Value("${swat.datasource.url}")
    private String dbURL;

    @Value("${swat.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driverName;

    @Value("${swat.datasource.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${swat.datasource.password}")
    private String hashedPassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        // String password = encryptor.decrypt(hashedPassword);
        // log.debug("password is: " + password);
        String password = null;;
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = new ProcessBuilder(fileLocation, hashedPassword).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Could not read the file", e);
            return null;
        }
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                password = line;
                try {
                    password = line.split(" ")[1].trim();
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    log.error("Error while sanitating the password", ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Could not process the file output", e);
        }
        PoolProperties poolProperties = new PoolProperties();
        poolProperties.setUrl(dbURL);         
        poolProperties.setUsername(userName);            
        poolProperties.setPassword(password);
        poolProperties.setDriverClassName(driverName);
        poolProperties.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolProperties.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        poolProperties.setValidationInterval(0);
        DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(poolProperties);
        process.destroy();
        return ds;
       // return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(dbURL).driverClassName(driverName).username(userName).password(password).build();
    }
```

this takes my encrypted password from the properties, decrypts it and than passes it to the database,
In all the flyway examples i've seen , the password is written as plain text in the flyway properties file

How can i configure it the way i'm using the primary datasource

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use environment variables to define your password.
To do that you can set the property as :

```
swat.datasource.password=${SWAT_PASSWORD}
```

and when you will deploy or run your application you just need to set the SWAT_PASSWORD variable in your environment.

you can also use a default value that the system will use it if the variable is not set

```
swat.datasource.password=${SWAT_PASSWORD:default_password}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal but it adds complexity we have a seperate instalation for each client, i want it to be done on code

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Flyway Bean by adding your own data source and configuration to Flyway where you can pass your own decrypted password. You will now have to manually configure Flyway in this Bean as auto-configuration will no longer work in order to use other Flyway properties.

```
@Configuration
public class FlywayConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.flyway.url}")
    private String flywayUrl;

    @Value("${spring.flyway.user}")
    private String flywayUser;

    @Value("${spring.flyway.password}")
    private String flywayPassword;

    // can still use spring.flyway.enabled
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.flyway", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.flyway")
    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    public Flyway flyway() {

        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();

        try {
            PoolProperties prop = new PoolProperties();
            prop.setUrl(flywayUrl);
            prop.setUsername(flywayUser);
            prop.setPassword(flywayPassword); // Add custom code to decrypt password
            dataSource = new DataSource(prop);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Configure Flyway with other properties if necessary
        return Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource).load();
    }
}
```

More information on the Flyway Java API:

- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/
- [Execute Flyway Database Migrations on Startup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup)